# handling exception in nest jest microservice using rabbitMq

Tags: typescript, exception, nestjs, microservices

[image]

there is problem in this microservice ,

if I throw some exception in `users Service` it must returned back to gateway and then to `client`

but it doesn't ! and **client** just see default `500` server error

I have used RPC exception filter in both **client** and **users** services

**rpc-exception.filter.ts**

```js
import { Catch, RpcExceptionFilter, ArgumentsHost } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Catch(RpcException)
export class MicroserviceExceptionFilter implements RpcExceptionFilter<RpcException> {
    catch(exception: RpcException, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
        return throwError(() => exception.getError());
    }
}
```

and this is gateway **main.ts**

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const environmentService = app.get(EnvironmentService);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new MicroserviceExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(environmentService.getAppPort());
}
bootstrap();
```

so how can I display **exception** that happens in some service to user ?

Answer (score 1):

You can return an error to gateway if you convert your handler as follows:

```
import { Catch, RpcExceptionFilter, ArgumentsHost } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Catch(RpcException)
export class MicroserviceExceptionFilter implements RpcExceptionFilter<RpcException> {
    catch(exception: RpcException, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
        return of(exception.getError());
    }
}
```